# About 2D plotting

Tags: plotting

In the following pic I want to show the error bar plotting with some given data: Y axis: 5.86*10^(-8) with error .58*10^(-8) and X axis: 0.1 to 2 (that means there is a range), 2.56*10^(-8) with error 0.25*10^(-8) and X axis: 2 to 5.0, etc. What command I will use?[image]

Comment: Please give a more detailed description of what you want.

Comment: Actually in my plotting I am only varying the X axis according of which Y axis is varying automatically. It starts from -0.96 along Y axis. But if I want to show this variation from zero value of Y axis then what command I will use?

Comment: I think you want to use the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) option,

Comment: Yes. But I want to change the range of Y axis as well as X axis.

Comment: PlotRange is for both the x and the y axis

Comment: Ok. Please give me the command of changing the plot range for both X and Y axis.

Comment: Look up `PlotRange` in the documentation. Under "Basic Examples", the second example shows you what the proper syntax is for specifying the plot ranges for both x and y axes. Use the documentation! It's very good.

Answer (score 1):

Use `PlotRange` as @BobHanlon suggested. For example,

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Now with `PlotRange`

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 6}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me such a type of example.

Comment: My another question is how I can plot error bar by taking the different ranges of x axis with respect to certain values of y axis with error.

Comment: You have to use [ErrorListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html) for that.

Comment: Suppose my data are along Y axis: 5.86 with error .58 within the range of X axis as 0.1 to 2. In the similar way 2.56 with error 0.25 within the range 2 to 5. Then how can I plot. Please give me an example

Comment: In my above fig I can not understand what command I will use?

Comment: @PritiNayek It is considered very rude here to change the question as substantially as you did after answers have already been coming in. You may define the upper and lower error function with `Piecewise` and plot the resulting functions with `Plot`.

Comment: I don't understand. Please explain clearly.